# how to print a variable into a text box

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

hi all
 I have a one variable. i want to print that varible into a text box. how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only display the string data in text box (`UITextView`),if you have other than string data it require a conversion to NSString then use the `text` properity of `UITextView` to set the display text.
The below code is for your reference.

```
NSString* myData  = @"dISPLAY me in text box";
UITextView* myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:myframe];
myTextView.text = myData;
```

Answer (score 1):

write

```
NSString * str=@"Text";

myTextField.text=str;
```

myTextField is the name of my textField(you can write the name of your text Field).

Comment: i am having an integer value in my varibale. i want to print that in my textbox.

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:"%d",myIntegerValue]

Answer (score 1):

```
yourTextField.text = yourVariable;
```

If you want to have it as a string value you can make use of `stringValue`

Answer (score 0):

You create a UILabel object, add it as a subview of your view, and call setText: on it.

Unless you are asking how to do GUI programming in general.